# How to upload contacts as Iterable from Flutter to Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app which will upload all contacts to Firestore database with map type. But below code do not upload contacts to Firestore. Please help.

I have been trying to fetch contacts from my phone to Firestore using Flutter app. I used contact_services library to fetch contacts. Even after trying some similar examples, I could not my contacts to Firestore using map type. Where do I make changes so that I can upload all my contacts as map value to Firestore

```
final Iterable<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false);
Firestore.instance
            .collection('contacts')
            .document(firebaseUser.uid)
            .setData({
          'contact':{ contacts.map((Contact contact){ 'name': contacts.displayName,contacts.phone})}  
        });
```

I expected to display all my contacts in firestore with map type, but actual output is none were uploaded.

Comment: Are there any errors logged (viewed with logcat on Android, for example)?  Besides not seeing the contacts in the database, what have you done to troubleshoot?  Maybe the problem is not with the data type of the storage, but with the connection at a lower level?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have fixed this since this is an old post. But there are a few things incorrect with how you are using the map method id Dart.

1. You named your element variable "contact" and not "contacts" so that is the variable you should be referencing "contact" to get your information. So it would be contact.displayName.
2. You are not returning anything. Because there is no "=>" there is no implicit return and because there is no "return" there is no explicit return.
3. Also, what you are returning from the map method is an Iterable to the contact field.

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. Are you trying to insert a nested object? If so, your phone is also missing a key

Answer (score 0):

Little late but, this is for the reference for the Firestore version **^0.16.0**.

> // your list of contacts in _contacts.

```
List<Contact> _contacts = [];    

final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
CollectionReference _ref = _db.collection(collectionName);

Future<void> syncContacts({uid}) async {
  try {
    Map<String, dynamic> _data;
    if (_contacts != null)
      _data = {
        'contacts': _contacts
            .map((k) => {
                  'name ': k.displayName,
                  'phone': k.phones.first.value
                      .toString()
                      .replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s\b|\b\s"), "")
                      .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^\w\s]+'), '')
                })
            .toList(),
      };

    log(_data.toString());

    await _service.reference().doc(uid).set(_data, SetOptions(merge: true));
  } catch (e) {
    log(e.toString());
  } finally {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

P.S I have used **flutter_contact** library to get contacts from the device.